# Display message using javascript is success:data id empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax function that takes json data from the model and displays it in rows. The function works fine but I want to add a message if no data was returned. What I am trying is not working, debugging shows "accts" is undefined?

Any help would be great!

Javascript:

```
//Submit form
$(function submit() {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#searchResults").show();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/TAPost',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (accts) {
                    if (accts.success = false) {
                        $("#Error").text('No Accounts were found for the information provided.');
                    }
                    else {
                        $.each(accts, function (index, acct) {
                            $("#rows").append('<tr><td>' + acct.CustomerName + '</td><td>' + "     " + acct.SSN + '</td><td>' + "     " + acct.FHBOATAcctNumber + '</td><td>'
                                + "     " + acct.OriginalAcctNumber + '</td><td>' + "     " + acct.ProductType + '</td></tr>');
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You will have to implement that in error callback..

Comment: That's natural. if *no data was returned*, then `accts` **is** *undefined* (moreover it's a `success` callback - meaning that *something* is supposed to be returned). If you want to perform an action when connection fails, use `error` callback

Comment: @ArturFilipiak - It is displaying the error even when data is returned?

Comment: No, it performs when connection fails. If you want to run an action when `accts` is empty, use `if(!accts){...`. Also, you have syntax error in your `if` statement, should be: `accts.success == false` (double equals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your accts object does not contain a success property. If you hit that line of code means that your request was successful. You must test if you receive any data from the server.

This is how you can do it

```
success: function (accts) {
             if (!accts || ($.isArray(accts) && accts.lenght === 0) || $.isEmptyObject(accts)) {
                 $("#Error").text('No Accounts were found for the information provided.');
             }
```

First test if you have a value in your accts object then if you are using an array to send the data test it's lenght to know if it contains elements and last if you are sending data in an object test if it has any properties with data.

**{Edit}**

In the web you can send a success response with empty data. This means "you request was successful but we have no results to show you" and an error in case something different happened like "your request is not in a legal form" or "you are not authorized to make this request".

You can use this however you like, the web is flexible like that, but using an error to signal "no results" is considered by many a bad design. Failed request's have meaning on it's own usually linked to it's status code and there is already a status code to signal no data, the 204 or "No content". Use that instead.